# Filtering table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, html-table

I have this table which has seven columns, each column representing a specific value like so:

I also have five select boxes containing options which I want to use for filtering this data table.

So far, I have come up with this:

```
$('#mySelectBox').change(function() {

  var filtervar = $(this).val();

  $('tr td.someclass').each(function () {
      if ($(this).text() != filtervar) {
          $(this).parent().hide();
      } else {
          $(this).parent().show(); 
      }
  });
});
```

This code works for one selectbox. How can I tweak it so that I can use five different selectboxes for filtering?

Comment: What you're trying to do might have already been done with other plugins, have a look at [DataTables](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)

Comment: Why you dont want to use some allready existing libraries for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is already generic enough. Just change the select box from having `id`s to `class`es and target all select boxes with the proper `class`.

---

**Script:**

```
$('.filter').change(function() { /* ... code ... */ });
```

**HTML:**

```
<select class="filter"> ... </select>
<select class="filter"> ... </select>
<select class="filter"> ... </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I tweak it so that I can use five different selectboxes for
>   filtering?

Simply apply a ***class*** to all your select boxes, this way you will need only one selector:

```
$('.selectBox').change.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give your select lists all the same class, such as "mySelectClass", and then use that in the selector instead of an ID.

```
$('.mySelectClass').change(function() {
```